# having issues while saving data to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am inserting data to database using codeigniter. But it keeps giving me below error

```
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'</p><p>INSERT INTO `profile` (`loginid`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `profilePhoto`, `date`) VALUES (Array, 'Zafar Khan', 'xafar@demo.com', 'male', '20.01.1987', '', '2012/11/19')

Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/membership_system/models/model_register.php</p><p>Line Number: 48
```

Here is the code where this error occurs

```
public function saveUserProfile() {
    $userId = $this->readUserId();

    $profile = array(
            'loginid'       => $userId,
            'name'          => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
            'gender'        => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'birthday'      => $this->input->post('birthday'),
            'profilePhoto'  => '',
            'date'          => date("Y/m/d")
        );

    $query = $this->db->insert('profile', $profile);

    if ($query) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

here is readUserId function

```
private function readUserId() {
    $this->db->select('id'); 
    $this->db->from('login');   
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my output for var_dump

```
array(1) {  [0]=>  object(stdClass)#18 (1) {    ["id"]=>    string(2) "14"  } }
```

Comment: Change 'date' array name , then check .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `$this->readUserId()` returns an Array.
Can you try `reset($this->readUserId());` ?
Put it before initializing $profile.

Or just

```
echo var_dump( $this->readUserId() );

die();
```

..So that we can see what's inside your variable.

==> EDIT:

$profile must become something like

```
$profile = array(
            'loginid'       => $userId['id'],
            'name'          => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
            'gender'        => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'birthday'      => $this->input->post('birthday'),
            'profilePhoto'  => '',
            'date'          => date("Y/m/d")
        );
```

==> EDIT 2:

Okay, then you can add

```
$userId = $userId[0]->id;
```

Before the $profile variable initialization.

Comment: yes it does return array. how can I fix this? I only need id from this array.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't know what is eally returned by this method. Can you show me the var_dump?

Answer (score 4):

The value of `$userId` is resulting in an unquoted `Array` being entered into the values which is being treated as a column reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your "userid" field is an array. There is another "userid" filed in your post.
look for duplicate names in your view file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in $this->readUserId() that is returning an array in place of an scalar. Please check it.